# cant save data from 1 table to another table

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

In cakephp I cant get the data returned from 1 table to be saved in another table.
I have data pre-populated  in a form from the Tutors table and all I want to do is save this data  as a new row in table tutorEdit (not confused with an edit function).
The issue I get is that I get the data to save but tutorEdit doesnt save any of the data  returned (no error).

```
public function tutor_edit($id = null) {
        $this->loadModel('Tutor');

        $this->Tutor->id = $id;

        debug($this->request->data );

        if (!$this->Tutor->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid tutor'));
        }
        if ($this->request->is('post')  ) {

            if ($this->TutorEdit->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The tutor details to be edited have ben forwarded to management'), 'flash_success');
               // $this->redirect(array('controller'=> 'tutors' , 'action' => 'tutordetails'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The tutor edit details could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'flash_alert');
            }



        } else {
            $this->request->data = $this->Tutor->read(null, $id);
        }

/////
   <?php
                    echo $this->Form->create('Tutor',array('class' => 'form-horizontal'));
                    echo $this->Form->input('id', $formHorizontalHtmlOptions);
                    echo $this->Form->input('first_name', $formHorizontalHtmlOptions);
                    echo $this->Form->input('last_name', $formHorizontalHtmlOptions);
                    echo $this->Form->input('email', $formHorizontalHtmlOptions);
                    echo $this->Form->input('mobile', $formHorizontalHtmlOptions);
                    echo $this->Form->input('home_phone', $formHorizontalHtmlOptions);
                    echo $this->Form->input('work_phone', $formHorizontalHtmlOptions);
                    echo $this->Form->input('gender', array_merge($formHorizontalHtmlOptions, array('type' => 'select', 'options' => $gender)));
                    echo $this->Form->end('Save Edit Request');   
                    ?>
```

didnt see anything about this in http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the data you are trying to save is 'Tutor', not 'TutorEdit'. In that link you shared, the first section shows the proper array format that needs to be saved.

Try this:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')  ) {
    $tutoredit = array('TutorEdit' => $this->request->data['Tutor']);

    if ($this->TutorEdit->save($tutoredit)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The tutor details to be edited have ben forwarded to management'), 'flash_success');
    } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The tutor edit details could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'flash_alert');
    }
}
```

Comment: This didnt work. I dint get an error but no data was saved even though the request->data is correct

Comment: it did work with a put instead of post? also I need extra fields in the tutorEdit as well as the tutor data . I want to add this in the controller but how do I do this?

Comment: @ajt - Extra fields - Just add them to the form (making sure their names are the names of the TutorEdit fields). In terms of a 'put', use an 'OR' (`||`) in the `if` clause

Comment: The extra fields are not for user input so how do I add these from the controller?I tried a few things but I am confused on how to add fields.

Comment: Alslo I cant use put because this is overwriting current data and i need post where a new row is added each time. This is a little harder than i thought

Comment: @ajt : add them to the array. For example, you need the field 'foo' to have the value 'bar' - `$tutoredit['TutorEdit']['foo']='bar'`

Comment: ok I can add fields as you said  but I cant add a new row as I need post. I keep getting same row updated and I dont want this. I need post to work. if ($this->request->is('post')

Comment: @ajt - Forget about "post vs. put" - that's an http "thing". 'Saving existing vs. adding a new' is a Cakephp problem to solve. You are "saving" because you are using the **id** field. You need to `unset` that value and use the `create` method.  These comments have digressed from your original question. You need to create a new question for this problem

Comment: i cant post a new question but i will try later. I cant find anything on unset?