# add in a field to a array with multiple records

Tags: php, cakephp

There has to be a simple answer but I cant add in a field to a array with multiple records     . I can do it with a single records but multiple records are different. The below code doesnt allow me to save a record. I can use another save command and add the records but no extra fields.

To makes things clearer I can save multiple records at once. I can add fields to these records manually as I need to add additional fields that the user cant add in themselves.

The problem is also i dont want to save associated models and just 1 model, so saveAssociated is not what i want. I dont want to save availabilityfortutors

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html

[cant save data from 1 table to another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26161251/cant-save-data-from-1-table-to-another-table/26161699#26161699)

```
 if ($this->request->is('post')) {
             $this->Availtmp->create();
             $Availtmp = array('Availtmp' => $this->request->data['AvailabilityForTutor']);

           $Availtmp['Availtmp'][0]['tutor_id'] = 2; //these fields I want to add in
     //  $Availtmp[1]['Availtmp']['tutor_id'] = 2;

         debug($Availtmp[0]['tutor_id']) ; //this works but it wont save in saveAll


             if ($this->Availtmp->saveAll($Availtmp)) {..
     //if ($this->Availtmp->saveAll($this->request->data['AvailabilityForTutor']) ){//this works

data
array(
    'Availtmp' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'weekday' => 'Monday',
            'start_time' => array(
                'hour' => '09',
                'min' => '00',
                'meridian' => 'am'
            ),
            'end_time' => array(
                'hour' => '11',
                'min' => '00',
                'meridian' => 'pm'
            ),
            'id' => '99'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'weekday' => 'Tuesday',
            'start_time' => array(
                'hour' => '09',
                'min' => '00',
                'meridian' => 'am'
            ),
            'end_time' => array(
                'hour' => '10',
                'min' => '00',
                'meridian' => 'pm'
            ),
            'id' => '100'
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'weekday' => 'Wednesday',
            'start_time' => array(
                'hour' => '12',
                'min' => '00',
                'meridian' => 'am'
            ),
            'end_time' => array(
                'hour' => '12',
                'min' => '00',
                'meridian' => 'am'
            ),
            'id' => '101'
        ),
        (int) 3 => array(
            'weekday' => 'Thursday',
            'start_time' => array(
                'hour' => '12',
                'min' => '00',
                'meridian' => 'am'
            ),
            'end_time' => array(
                'hour' => '12',
                'min' => '00',
                'meridian' => 'am'
            ),
            'id' => '102'
        ),
        (int) 4 => array(
            'weekday' => 'Friday',
            'start_time' => array(
                'hour' => '12',
                'min' => '00',
                'meridian' => 'am'
            ),
            'end_time' => array(
                'hour' => '12',
                'min' => '00',
                'meridian' => 'am'
            ),
            'id' => '103'
        ),
        (int) 5 => array(
            'weekday' => 'Saturday',
            'start_time' => array(
                'hour' => '09',
                'min' => '00',
                'meridian' => 'am'
            ),
            'end_time' => array(
                'hour' => '11',
                'min' => '00',
                'meridian' => 'pm'
            ),
            'id' => '104'
        ),
        (int) 6 => array(
            'weekday' => 'Sunday',
            'start_time' => array(
                'hour' => '12',
                'min' => '00',
                'meridian' => 'am'
            ),
            'end_time' => array(
                'hour' => '12',
                'min' => '00',
                'meridian' => 'am'
            ),
            'id' => '105'
        )
    ),
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Availtmp' => array(
            'tutor_id' => (int) 2
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'Availtmp' => array(
            'tutor_id' => (int) 2
        )
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'Availtmp' => array(
            'tutor_id' => (int) 2
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: well what more info is needed. I followed the code for a single record, I asked a different question before , I researched it  and my code gets the data to save but it doesnt add a field in so what am I supposed to do? The docs say nothing on the point?

Comment: I think I confused people as I dont want any associated models saved. I just want the Availtmp model data saved and not the Availabikityforstudents. SaveAssociated didnt solve the problem either

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and it appears you cant add extra fields into a multi record array and save the whole thing in another table .
If you have an array of records and you want to copy just this to another table(model) with extra fields for the table to copy to, you wont have any luck.